# Jest cannot locate @babel/code-frame when trying to use @ alias

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, jestjs

Our app imports files using `import` ES2015 style syntax, utilizing Webpack `4.6.0` native support for ES2015 modules. We also use an alias to shorten our relative file paths.

**Webpack.conf.js**

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.less'],
        alias: {
            '@': resolve('public/js'),
            'handlebars': 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.js',
        },
        modules: ['less', 'node_modules']
    },
```

**example.js**

```
import widget from '@/widgets/widget';
```

**file structure**

```
- webpack.conf.js
- .babelrc
- test/
- public/
- - js/
- - - widgets/
- - - - widget.js
```

When I imported for example `example.js`, which has an alias'd `import`, Jest would throw an error, "cannot resolve module '@/widgets/widget'.

According to a [remarkably specific article](https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/10/07/Enhance-Jest-configuration-with-Module-Aliases/) as well as the [Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html), the solution is to use Jest's `ModuleNameMapper` config property to set up matching alias'. I have attempted to do so:

**package.json**

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
      "@(.*)$": "<rootDir>/public/js/$1"
    },
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "globals": {
      "NODE_ENV": "test"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
```

As well as properly configure babel:

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "modules": false,
                "test": {
                    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
                }
            }
        ],
        "es2015",
        "stage-2"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
}
```

Now, when I run Jest (with the `--no-cache` flag just in case), I get this error:

```
test/test.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:

    Could not locate module @babel/code-frame (mapped as /home/calebjay/Documents/ide/public/js/babel/code-frame)

    Please check:

    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "/@(.*)$/": "/home/calebjay/Documents/ide/public/js/$1"
    },
    "resolver": undefined
```

I can't find `@babel/code-frame` anywhere outside of `package-lock.json`, and just for giggles I stripped all mentions of `@{{anything}}` from there and ran tests again, same result.

Is jest stepping over babel somehow? How can I get my tests to run with Jest using aliases?

EDIT: To try to narrow down what is calling `@babel/code-frame`, I tried deleting `es2015` and `stage-2` from `.babelrc`, to no effect. I tried deleting the `transform` property of the Jest config in `package.json`, to no effect. I tried deleting the `env.test.plugins` property from `.babelrc`, to no effect. Same error.

EDIT2: Thinking maybe some other package is requiring it, I checked `package.json`. It seems `jest-message-util` requires `@babel/code-frame`. I do see `@babel/code-frame` in my node_modules though... so perhaps the problem is that jester is saying "ok, all instances of @, turn into public/js" ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
"@(.*)$": "<rootDir>/public/js/$1"
```

will convert `@babel/code-frame` to

```
"<rootDir>/public/js/babel/code-frame"
```

which doesn't exist. You need to make your pattern more specific and do

```
"@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/public/js/$1"
```

Note the additional `/` at the beginning. That way it will still match your `@/widgets/widget`, but it won't match other scoped packages.

Comment: Yup, that was it! I went a more hilarious route and tried `((^(?!@babel).*$)((?!@)(.*)$))` , which didn't work for some reason.